# Для чего используются методы изменения значений полей класса, если можно изменить значение напрямую?

Tags: javascript, ооп, ecmascript-6

Разбираюсь потихоньку в javascript. Есть класс Weather в нем несколько свойств объявлено, вроде этого. И в нем функция(метод) для изменения этого самого свойства.

```
class Weather {
 constructor() {
   this.location;
   // ну и т.д.
 }

 changeLocation(location) {
   this.location = location;
 }
}
```

В примере это выглядит как

```
const weather = new Weather();
const location = 'London, UK';

weather.changeLocation(location);
```

Мне не совсем понятно зачем здесь функция(метод)? Ведь можно просто

```
const weather = new Weather();
const location = 'London, UK';

weather.location = location;
```

Не проще ли так ? И не надо дергать функцию(метод). Как правильно? Как это принято делать?

Comment: Функция нужна для того, чтобы перед строчкой `this.location =` или после неё можно было сделать ещё что-нибудь — например, проверить, что значение `location` корректно. С простым присваиванием `weather.location =` это сделать не получится (хотя на самом деле получится с defineProperty, но сейчас не об этом), а в функции — без проблем

Comment: Спасибо, это все понятно. Не понятно зачем для простого присваивания здесь метод дергать. При надобности можно всегда ведь после обернуть. Интересно насколько корректен второй вариант(без вызова метода)?

Comment: А насчет проверок. Не знаю как кто, но я привык проверять данные до того как их присваивать.

Comment: Я ж говорю, в будущем это может стать сложнее, чем просто присваивание. Если не будет функции, то для обновления функциональности придётся переделывать ВСЕ-ВСЕ места, где стоит это присваивание (а их может быть сотни и тысячи или вообще бесконечно много), а в случае с функцией — достаточно поправить функцию в одном месте

Comment: Вот «проверять данные до того как их присваивать» как раз и делается в функции перед присваиванием)

Comment: В ответе всего одного слово - Инкапсуляция. Дальше можно нагуглить статей и почитать. Пригодится ещё не раз.

Answer (score 3):

Хорошей практикой является изменение свойств объекта через функцию. Это нужно для того, что ты или другой разработчик (если проект командный) не смог просто взять и поменять это свойство на что угодно. В случае с функцией ты сможешь добавлять всякие проверки на корректность нового значения.

```js
class Weather {
 constructor() {
   this.location;
 }

 changeLocation(location) {
   if (typeof location !== 'string') {
     throw new Error('Invalid location value');
   }
   
   this.location = location;
 }
}

const invalidLocation = [1,2,3, {test: 3}]; // невалидный тип
const validLocation = 'London, UK'; //валидный тип

const weather1 = new Weather();
weather1.location = invalidLocation; // таким кодом ты сможешь сломать свое приложение, но с сточки зрения кода все ок)


const weather2 = new Weather();
weather2.changeLocation(invalidLocation); // получишь ошибку и это свойство не будет присваиваться

const weather3 = new Weather();
weather3.changeLocation(validLocation); // ошибки не будет и код отработает корректно
```